# Chatterbot does not reply when I create a while loop

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am making a basic chat bot using Chatterbot, however, I don't want to build the entire project every time I want to give an input.

```
Here is my code:

from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from reader import Sub2Convo

bot = ChatBot("bot")


trainer= ListTrainer(bot)
trainer.train(Sub2Convo("sherlock01"))
trainer.train(Sub2Convo("sherlock02"))

while True:
    try:
        bot_input = bot.get_response(input())
        print(bot_input)

    except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

After the build is complete and I give "Hello" as the input nothing happens.

```
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
List Trainer: [####################] 100%

hello
```

If I remove the **while** loop like below everything works correctly.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from reader import Sub2Convo

chatbot = ChatBot("bot")


trainer= ListTrainer(chatbot)
trainer.train(Sub2Convo("sherlock01"))
trainer.train(Sub2Convo("sherlock02"))

response = chatbot.get_response("hello")
print(response)
```

output:

```
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
List Trainer: [####################] 100%

Hi There
[Finished in 13.9s]
```

Comment: At first glance the code looks sensible, have you done any debugging?

Comment: No I haven't and honestly I don't know how to do it. I use sublime text 3 and I am new to this.

Comment: _No I haven't and honestly I don't know how to do it. I use sublime text 3 and I am new to this._ Then Stack Overflow might not be the place for this. See [help/on-topic], [ask]. You might find the following article useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.